# How to write tick marks and brackets with Ansible 'lineinfile' module?

Tags: ansible, special-characters

I am trying to write the following string with Ansible `lininfile`.

The failing Ansible task:

```yaml
- name: Insert GetInterfaceIP
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/consul.d/consul.hcl
    regexp: '^advertise'
    line: advertise_addr = "{{ GetInterfaceIP `eth0` }}"
```

Desired result in the file:

```
advertise_addr = "{{ GetInterfaceIP `eth0` }}"
```

How can I escape the special characters so that the line is written to the file exactly like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent the given string from [Templating](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_templating.html), you might take advantage from [Unsafe or raw strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_advanced_syntax.html#unsafe-or-raw-strings).

The following example will add the exact string into the file

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Add unsafe text line
    lineinfile:
      path: test.txt
      line: !unsafe 'advertise_addr = "{{ GetInterfaceIP `eth0` }}"'
```

resulting into an output of

```bash
tail -1 test.txt
advertise_addr = "{{ GetInterfaceIP `eth0` }}"
```

since

> *Marking data as unsafe prevents malicious users from abusing Jinja2 templates to execute arbitrary code on target machines. The Ansible implementation ensures that unsafe values are never templated.*

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible throws error after variable content is copied into fact](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72029659/6771046)
- [Unsafe variables in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45028897/)

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly! Unfortunately I can't upvote your answer because of this message from stackoverflow:

Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Comment: But you can accept it as answer if it answer your question and resolve the problem. By doing this you'll gain also reputation.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen the check mark. :)